# UpdateOne working on mongo shell but not in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have the following query which works fine in mongo shell but unable to work on mongoose driver

shell command

```
db.deviceregisters.updateOne({SRN:"1234",code:"password"},{$set:{'ip.update':true}})
```

mongoose driver

```
const res = await deviceRegister.updateOne({dSRN:req.params.SRN,code:req.params.code},{$set {'ip.update':false}})
```

Comment: `but unable to work on mongoose` ... what exactly is the problem?  Is there any error message?

Comment: No error , return { ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }

Comment: console.log both the fields `req.params.SRN`, `req.params.code`, and make sure correct input values.

Comment: Try to add debugging details always in your question, we don't have any superpower to run and debug your code on your PC, how we can help you without seeing your actual input and implementation.

Comment: hello turivishal , thanks for your comment will surly add next time , actually I missed to add. but later comment by Tim i posted.

Answer (score 1):

I got the issue as in database I manually add the column using shell command but forgot the update the schema so after update the schema it works .

Thanks